# Why is my android app only show up in playstore when using quotation marks "titleOfApp"?

Tags: android, google-play, publish, quotation-marks, viewroot

Hello my favorite community.

Maybe someone has the answer out there
I recently put my first app to the play store market and after a couple of hours it appears there. But the thing is the first days i did not recognized that it was already on the market caused by the problem i cant find it. So i taught i need to update it  to another version by adding some language support stuff.
After found a hint on this lovely board that some apps will only appear in search query by put the app name into quotation marks. But why is that and do somebody know how i should change the name of the app to get a better search result.

i already changed from Camel Case Notation "myAppTitle" to "my app title" but this was not really a solution for my problem.

moreover i had the same issue like many others with some android devices. my app seems to run on almost 70% of the devices (since android v14) but on some devices that exception raises:

viewrootimpl senduseractionevent() mview == null

some people have same problems almost with samsung devices...an answer i found was that samsung has an special android layer for touch wizard. but how to work arround that problem?

Thanks in advanced.

here an excerpt from the layout which causes this problem..

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- ROW -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView__game_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="anyText"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView__game_word1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/yellow"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="anyText?"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView__game_word2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="anyText?"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView__game_word3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="anytext?"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView__game_score"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Score:\n0"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView__game_round"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="Round:\n 0 of 100"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my above explained problems.

First, the layout problem and the message:
"viewrootimpl senduseractionevent() mview == null"

is easily solved by changing the layout to a Linear Layout. Moreover I changed from TextViews to Buttons that solved the issue why my app did not funtcion correctly on 30% of all android devices like samsung galaxy s3 and so on.
These devices had a problem with onClicks on Textviews and therefore by using Buttons the problem was fixed.
The viewrootimpl... is still null but do not have any influence to the behaviour of my app...like in many other post u can just ignore this log output.

Second, the reason why my app is not visible by using the search funtcion in google play market without the use of "myapp title" is the internal ranking of apps made by google.
The ranking of apps in play store depends on different factors. One is the ratings made by users. But one crucial factor is the ranking by keywords used in app title.
If you use frequent used keywords in your app title then your app would be easily found, but if you use an app title which do not contains any keyword, your app will only be found by using quoation marks.
So I changed my app title by adding some keywords at the end and after updating it to the play store, i immediately found my app by using the search function of the market.

Hopefully, this post will help others which struggle with the same problems.
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Since you app is new, Google Play will only show top results, that's why you have trouble finding your app. If your app download count have raised to thousand or more, it will more easy to be search by others.

Comment: i guess what u talking about is ranking? the main problem is that i cant find it anyway without using "myapptitle" indepently of my app rank or entry in the list of apps